# Sorting CSV records by date Python Flask

Tags: python-3.x, flask

Is it possible to sort the values of a CSV file by date records in the file and print them out with Flask Python
This is what i have so far 
The python flask :

```
def readFile(file):
    with open(file, 'r') as inFile:
        reader = csv.reader(inFile)
        listCSV = [row for row in reader]
    return listCSV

def writeFile(list, file):
    with open(file, 'w', newline='') as outFile:
        writer = csv.writer(outFile)
        writer.writerows(list)
    return  


@app.route('/bookings', methods = ['GET'])
def bookings():
    bookingCSV = 'static\\bookingList.csv'
    listCSV = readFile(bookingCSV)
    return render_template('booking.html', listCSV=listCSV)

@app.route('/addBooking', methods = ['POST'])
def addBooking():
    bookingCSV = 'static\\bookingList.csv'
    listCSV = readFile(bookingCSV)

    name = request.form[('name')]
    email = request.form[('email')]
    startDate = request.form[('startDate')]
    endDate = request.form[('endDate')]
    booking = "To be processed"
    newEntry = [name, email, startDate, endDate, booking]
    listCSV.append(newEntry)

    writeFile(listCSV, bookingCSV)
    return render_template('booking.html', listCSV=listCSV)
```

and the html that prints it all out

```
{% for row in listCSV %}
<div class="bookingData">
    <br><p>Start Date: {{ row[2] }}&nbsp;|&nbsp;End Date: {{ row[3] }}&nbsp;|&nbsp;Booked Status: {{ row[4] }}</p><br>
</div>
 {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on whether or not you want to sort the list in place, you either want `list.sort` or `sorted`. Both functions accept a [key function](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#key-functions) that can be used to define how you want to do the sort. In your case, you'll probably want to use a lambda function to return the value at the index containing the date you want to sort by.

```
listCSV.sort(key=lambda row: row[2])  # or whatever index you want to use
```